# Chrome JavaScript Errors on Non-Breaking Space

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, character-encoding

We have a thrid-party javascript component that instead of ordinary spaces has non-breaking ones, i.e. when looked at in the editor we get c2a0 as the character for the space.

This script when loaded into a browser seems to work mostly fine, but on Chrome in Ubuntu this character becomes a capital A with a circumflex atop of it; this of course causes errors.  Now we have removed all the offending characters but would still like to lnow why this might have happened?

Comment: It would perhaps be helpful to examine the HTTP headers.

Comment: Which ones in particular?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is that I hadn't correctly specified the character encoding on my html page.  With a correct encoding of "utf-8" set up, everything works as expected.